# Exact phrase with special characters in Lucene.net

Tags: .net, lucene, phrase

i've a problem doing a full text search in lucene.net where the search result contains special lucene characters.

I've a field named "content" in my Lucene documents. This field is created as followed and contains the content of the indexed documents:

```
document.Add(new Field("content", fulltext, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

For creating the index i'm using the Standardanalyzer.

For querying the index i'm using the following code:

```
var queryParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "content", analayzer);
queryParser.SetAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
queryParser.SetMultiTermRewriteMethod(MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_QUERY_REWRITE);
Query fullTextQuery = queryParser.Parse(queryString);
```

The query is then added to a BooleanQuery which is used to get the results from a IndexSearcher. I think the rest of the code is not that important, because the code works like it should for 99% of the queries.  I'm also using the StandardAnalyzer for querying the index.

Now here is the problem.
Sometimes the "content" field of a document contains text that is separated using "-"

> some text some text selector-lever some text some text

Now when i'm doing a full text search (exact phrase) using "selector lever". The query looks like this:

> content:"selector lever"

The problem here is that also the document containing the above text is found, although it shouldn't be found because the 2 words are separated using the "-" and not blank.

I think it has something to do with the analyzer and the fact that "-" is a special character in lucene.

Maybe someone can help me solving this problem.

thanks in advance
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You are right in thinking that the problem is the analyzer that you are using at index time.

From the [Lucene javadocs](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html):

> A grammar-based tokenizer constructed with JFlex
>
> This should be a good tokenizer for most European-language documents:
>
> - Splits words at punctuation characters, removing punctuation. However, a dot that's not followed by whitespace is considered part of a token.
> - **Splits words at hyphens, unless there's a number in the token, in which case the whole token is interpreted as a product number and is not split**.
> - Recognizes email addresses and internet hostnames as one token.
>
> Many applications have specific tokenizer needs. If this tokenizer does not suit your application, please consider copying this source code directory to your project and maintaining your own grammar-based tokenizer.

Therefore, in your case you would need to index your documents with a more strict Analyzer like the `WhitespaceAnalyzer` which only splits on whitespace.

Comment: a question after 4 years. As standard analyzer remove punctuations, when it comes to search, the query parser also removes the punctuations. This result in highlighter, marking the words ignoring the last/first punctuation of the word. I dont want to use the WhitespaceAnalyzer as it restrict the search results. Any idea on how to overcome last punctuation of the word not being highlighted?

Comment: @JenonD It's been too long that I don't think I can help you. I'd suggest posting a new question and reference this one if you like.